# React Native - Best way to send and receive events within Javascript thread

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-bridge

I want to know which is the best way to send and receive events only within the JS stack. The event which is being emitted should not reach the react-native bridge or simply I don't want the event to reach the android/iOS stack.

I know using NativeEventEmitter, we can send and receive event inside JS stack, but unsure whether this will pass the data through react native bridge. I want a optimised way of sending and receiving events within the JS stack.

Please help me find the right approach.

Thanks.